# Dry a simple jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a designer and code isn't my strong. I make this code that works as expected, by I would like to DRY it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#configurable_swatch_color li.is-media a[name=preto]').on('click', function(){

  $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-bege]" ).parent().css('display','none');

  $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-cafe]" ).parent().css('display','none');

  $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-preta]" ).parent().css('display','list-item');


 });

 $('#configurable_swatch_color li.is-media a[name=caf-]').on('click', function(){

  $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-bege]" ).parent().css('display','none');

  $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-preta]" ).parent().css('display','none');

  $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-cafe]" ).parent().css('display','list-item');


 });

 $('#configurable_swatch_color li.is-media a[name=bege]').on('click', function(){

  $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-preta]" ).parent().css('display','none');

  $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-cafe]" ).parent().css('display','none');

  $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-bege]" ).parent().css('display','list-item');


 });

});
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
$('#configurable_swatch_color li.is-media').on('click', 'a[name]', function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item" ).find("a[title]").each(function (){
      if ($(this).attr("title").indexOf(name) > -1) {
        $(this).parent().css("display", "list-item");
      }
      else {
        $(this).parent().css("display", "none");
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: This was also in my mind as an answer to the OP's question. To simplifiy his code to fewer lines by preserving functionality. The OP should give the green checkmark for this

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //get all the links that you care about, store them in an jQuery object for later reference
    var $mediaLinks = $('#configurable_swatch_color li.is-media a').filter(function(){ return ['preto','caf-','bege'].indexOf(this.name) > -1; });
    var $carouselLinks = $("#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a").filter(function(){ return ['cor-bege','cor-cafe','cor-preta'].indexOf(this.title) > -1; });
    //map your names to your titles
    var titlesByName = [
        preto: 'cor-preta'
        , 'caf-': 'cor-cafe'
        , bege: 'cor-bege'
    ];

    $mediaLinks.on('click', function(e){
        //get related carousellink
        var $carouselLink = $carouselLinks.filter(function(){ return this.title === titlesByName[e.target.name]; });

        //if it is not already visible, hide other things and show it
        if ($carouselLink.parent().css('display') != 'list-item') {
            //hide others
            $carouselLinks.not($carouselLink).parent().hide();
            //and finally show the one clicked
            $carouselLink.parent().css('display', 'list-item');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See comments inline:

```js
$(function(){

  // You only need one function that shows/hides elements.
  // Simply, make that funciton expect the correct elements
  // be passed in to it.
  function doStuff(dispNoneArray, listItemObject){
    $(dispNoneArray).parent().css('display','none');
    $(listItemObject).parent().css('display','list-item');  
  }  
  
 // Now, just call the function when appropriate, and pass it the right objects: 
 $('#configurable_swatch_color li.is-media a[name=preto]').on('click', function(){
   doStuff([$( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-bege]" ).parent(),
           $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-cafe]" ).parent()], 
           $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-preta]" ));
 });

 $('#configurable_swatch_color li.is-media a[name=caf-]').on('click', function(){
   doStuff([ $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-bege]" ).parent(),
           $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-preta]" ).parent()], 
           $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-cafe]" ).parent());   
 });

 $('#configurable_swatch_color li.is-media a[name=bege]').on('click', function(){
   doStuff([ $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-preta]" ).parent(),
           $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-cafe]" ).parent()], 
           $( "#shopper_gallery_carousel .jcarousel-item a[title=cor-bege]" ).parent());    
 });
  
});
```

Comment: How is this DRY, again?

Comment: @mhodges Is it perfect? No. Does it convey the idea that you don't need 3 functions that do the same thing? Yes. Did you read the comments? No.

Comment: Did I read the comments? Yes. Is this answer useful for the OP and future users looking to DRY out their code? No. This is a very half-baked answer that does very little to solve the actual issue, which is 3 click handlers for nearly identical selectors, and 3 other nearly identical selectors/operations.

Comment: @mhodges That's your opinion. The answer very clearly indicates and shows how to combine 3 functions that only vary by elements into one. If you don't believe that's DRY, then you need to look up DRY. It's a very good example to convey the concept. As I said, does it take it all the way? No. But the OP (and future readers) have enough to take that ball and run with it.

Comment: The only thing I will say is this: I think you highly underestimate how often people copy/paste code they find on SO into production environments. You're doing the community a disservice by providing an answer like this without explaining that your answer is incomplete, and what else you would do to "take it all the way".